# implementing facebook like localy for testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I got my "like-code" from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. It is not working for some reason.

I see this is one of the problems from google development tools.

```
GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1
```

Is it possbile to test the like button from a html page that is not deployed on a server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cats Who Code demo</title>
<link href="col.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mysite.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible regardless otherwise "localhost" would probably be one of the most liked things on Facebook, though I could be wrong.But the specific issue you have is your just testing a html file by opening it, rather than testing it on a local webserver, hence the "file://" protocol. You need to install a server locally and browse to your page via localhost so it uses the correct http/https protocol. Also you already include the connect library in a script tag, why are you loading it again via a javascript function?

Comment: @TommyBs I am not trying to like localhost but like something else from localhost. Isnt that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the error you're getting is because you're running the html file over the file protocol, not over the http protocol

Comment: Thanks I will deploy and se how things go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy on localhost. That works.